# Render ASP.NET Core Razor markup from an argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

Before ASP.NET Core, I could pass Razor markup as an argument to some function. However, it doesn't seem to work anymore.

For example, even these simple cases render nothing:

```
@{
  Func<object, HelperResult> markup1 = @<text>hello world</text>;
  new HtmlString(markup1.Invoke(null).ToString());

  Func<object, HelperResult> markup2 = @<h1>hello world</h1>;
  new HtmlString(markup2.Invoke(null).ToString());
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "it renders nothing" - so it compiles/builds at least?

Comment: @Dai It compiles and runs, no errors. But that markup isn't rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wont render any result as you are not doing anything with the result.

```
@{
  Func<object, HelperResult> markup = @<text>hello world</text>;
  new HtmlString(markup.Invoke(null).ToString());
}
```

In the expression `new HtmlString(markup.Invoke(null).ToString());` returns a HTML Result which is correct however the way you are calling it will not work correctly. Here is a snippet that will print the result.

```
@{

    Func<object, HelperResult> markup = @<text>hello world</text>;
    var html = markup.Invoke(null);
    await html.WriteAction(ViewContext.Writer);
}
```

You will notice here we explicitly tell the html variable (`HtmlResult`) where to write to. In this instance you will want to write to the `ViewContext.Writer` which is a `System.IO.TextWriter`.